# How to export raster image using arcpy with dynamic range adjustment (DRA)?

Tags: arcpy, raster, export, jpg

I want to export raster satellite image into jpeg format as layout view (with scale bar, legend etc.).

I check on dynamic range adjustment (DRA) option in image analysis window. Manual export using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2 works well, but running the same procedure with a python script (see below) with the same mxd project gives other results than manual manipulations (somehow DRA option is disabled while executing script).

How to export raster image in layout view using arcpy with dynamic range adjustment (DRA)?

```
import arcpy
mxd_path = r"C:\project.mxd"
jpg_path = r"C:\test_image.jpg"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, jpg_path)
```